# Android navigation drawer failure

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, navigation-drawer

everybody, I am new in Android development and I am trying to create an app with custom navigation drawer. I have a code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this code creates a navigation drawer perfectly fine. Although, when I provide a layout like this, my navigation drawer seems to take place in whole screen and doesn't react to any actions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/navigation_menu_background" >

        <include layout="@layout/navigation_menu_header" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My JAVA code is:

```
 DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

 ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

        // TODO: Handle drawer open action here!
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

        // TODO: Handle drawer close action here!
    }
};

drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();

// Sets up navigation view.
ListView navigationListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_list_view);
NavigationMenuListAdapter navigationMenuListAdapter = new NavigationMenuListAdapter(this);

navigationListView.setAdapter(navigationMenuListAdapter);
navigationListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Where could be a problem causing this issue? And why is that so?

Comment: The `android:layout_gravity="start"` attribute needs to be on the View that you're using for the drawer; in this case, the `NavigationView`. You should also set the `layout_width` to `"wrap_content"`.

Comment: I have tested, `android:layout_gravity="start"` replacement has solved the issue! Please post your answer to allow me to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `android:layout_gravity="start"` attribute needs to be on the `View` that you're using for the drawer; in this case, the `NavigationView`.

You might also want to set the `layout_width` to `"wrap_content"`, so the drawer doesn't cover more of the content than it should. `NavigationView` will measure itself out to an appropriate width, but if you were to use another `View` that doesn't, you might need to use an exact measure instead of wrapping; e.g., `"240dp"`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's taking up the whole screen is because you have "match_parent" specified as the height and width values- it's matching the size of the entire view, and therefore the entire screen.

Comment: You mean for a `NavigationView`? Why is than `ListView` with `match_parent` works (look at my first code).